# was or were and them of they?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

> It **were/was** **they/them** who did that.

There are 4 possible variations of this sentence - but grammatically correct obviously only one. Which is the right way to say this sentence and others alike?

Comment: "It was they / them who did that". The nominative "they" is very formal, while almost everyone says "them".

Comment: You could also say, "It was them! They did it!"

Answer (score 2):

Less than four. The subject "it" requires only "was" here (being a singular pronoun) having no connection with conditional sentence.

So the rest are

> It was them/they who did that.

Comment: "Fewer" than four.

Answer (score 2):

Most people say "It was them".

A couple of centuries ago, some grammarians made up rules to make English more like Latin (and sell more grammar books), and taught people that it should be "It was they": generations of teachers have taught that form, and some people still say it.